# Change random operator or variable

Tags: java, random

I have an assignment in my programming class. It goes like this, I have to make a program which takes the input of the user how many exercises he wants to do. Then he solves simple calculations with random numbers from 1-10 and with random operators. In the end, it should write how many correct and incorrect ones did he get. It also should write the elapsed time of the task.
I did some work, but when I assign a random value to an operation

`int operation = (int)(Math.random()*3)+1;`

or to a number a and b

`int a = (int)(Math.random()*10);
 int b = (int)(Math.random()*10);`

I always get the same number and operator when I choose for the second or third time my task (because I use a loop). Is there a way to change the same initialized variable or operator during a program. For example that `int a=(int)(Math.Random()*10)` is initialized in the beginning as for example as 3, and later when the program loops again to initialize it as a different number, for example 6. Are there any others solutions for my problem?
Here is my whole code, for now:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class RandomChar {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    char op= ' ';
    int operation = (int)(Math.random()*3)+1;

    int a = (int)(Math.random()*10);
    int b = (int)(Math.random()*10);
    String s;
    int correct = 0, incorrect=0;

    s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many exercises do you want?");
    int num = Integer.parseInt(s);

    long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(num>0){

        if(operation==1)
        op='+';
    else if(operation==2)
        op='-';
    else if(operation==3)
        op='*';

    String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(a+" "+op+" "+b+" = ");
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);

    if(op=='+'){
    if(a+b==num1)
        correct++;
    else
        incorrect++;
    }else if(op=='-'){
        if(a-b==num1)
            correct++;
        else
            incorrect++;
    }else if(op=='*'){
        if(a*b==num1)
            correct++;
                    else
            incorrect++;
    }
    num--;
    }

    long tEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long tOverral = tEnd - tStart;
    double elapsedSeconds = tOverral / 1000.0;
    System.out.println("Correct: "+correct);
    System.out.println("Incorrect: "+incorrect);
    System.out.println("Elapsed seconds: "+ elapsedSeconds);


}
```

}

Comment: You can create a list of numbers and then call Collections.shuffle(list); method and then access the list from index 0 to last index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move the calculation of random numbers and the operator into your while-loop. Actually you calculate them once.

```
while (num > 0) {
    int operation = (int) (Math.random() * 3) + 1;

    int a = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int b = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    ...
}
```

So you'll have new numbers and operators in any exercise.